# Cloud Firestore - Consulta composta

Tags: firebase, mobile, react-native, firebase-database, firestore

Estou fazendo uma consulta no meu banco de dados no firestore, mas quando coloco dois `where` aninhados, recebo o seguinte erro:

```
Error getting documents Error: Firestore: Operation was rejected because the system is not in a state required for the operation`s execution. (firestore/failed-precondition).
```

Quando realizo a consulta com apenas um dos where, a consulta funciona.

Código:

```
firebase
  .firestore()
  .collection('users')
  .doc(userId)
  .collection('cars')
  .where('available', '==', true)
  .where('createdAt', '<=', new Date(moment().format('MMMM DD, YYYY')))
  .get()
  .then((snapshot) => {
      const cars = [];
      snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        cars.push(Object.assign({}, { id: doc.id }, doc.data()));
      });
      this.setState({ cars, loading: false });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
      console.log('Error getting documents', err);
      this.setState({ loading: false });
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parece relacionado a [esta Issue](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1437) (e várias outras pelo jeito).

[Essa](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/815#issuecomment-465741365) resposta em uma das Issues relacionadas me leva a crer que o problema tem a ver com esse trecho na documentação do firestore, na seção de [Índices Compostos](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview#composite_indexes):

> O Cloud Firestore usa índices compostos para oferecer suporte a consultas compostas que ainda não aceitam índices de campo único. Por exemplo, você precisaria de um índice composto para as seguintes consultas:
>
> ```
> citiesRef.where("country", "==", "USA").orderBy("population", "asc")
> citiesRef.where("country", "==", "USA").where("population", "<", 3800000)
> citiesRef.where("country", "==", "USA").where("population", ">", 690000)
> ```

Para essas consultas, por exemplo, seria necessário um índice composto em `country` e `population`.

No seu caso, esse índice teria que ser em `available` e `createdAt`.

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde,

Tenta fazer o seguinte, acessa o console do firebase, vai no firestore, na aba indices e cria um novo indice composto:

Coleção: cars 
com os campos: available Ascending e createAt Ascending

eu rodei o seguinte codigo com sucesso apos criar os indices:

```
getCars(userId) {
    const now = new Date();
    this.db.firestore
      .collection('users')
      .doc(userId)
      .collection('cars')
      .where('available', '==', true)
      .where('createAt', '<=', now)
      .get()
      .then( res => {
        console.log(res.docs);
      });
  }
```

Comment: Por que deve se criar índice composto?

Comment: o Firestore exige a criação de indices compostos quando são usados campos diferentes, se fosse um intervalo no campo createAt com <= e depois >= não precisa, mas se você tentar usar 2 campos diferentes no where como esse caso 'available' e 'createAr' precisa criar o indice direto no console.