# Como limitar uma consulta composta no Firebase/flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

Eu fiz uma consulta simples desta forma e funciona corretamente, ele salva apenas uma vez no banco de dados, não repetindo o mesmo valor.

```
  final QuerySnapshot result = await Future.value(Firestore.instance
      .collection("lockers")
      .where("numero_serie", isEqualTo: "$_numeroSerie")
      .limit(1)
      .getDocuments());
```

Mas eu preciso fazer uma consulta composta e não esta dando certo, tentei desse jeito e ele não salva nada no banco.

```
final QuerySnapshot result = await Future.value(Firestore.instance
    .collection("lockers")
    .where("userid", isEqualTo: "$_uid").limit(1)
    .where("numero_serie", isEqualTo: "$_numeroSerie").limit(1)
    .getDocuments());
```

Assim ele salva o mesmo valor no banco varias vezes

```
final QuerySnapshot result = await Future.value(Firestore.instance
    .collection("lockers")
    .where("userid", isEqualTo: "$_uid")
    .where("numero_serie", isEqualTo: "$_numeroSerie").limit(1)
    .getDocuments());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final QuerySnapshot result = await Future.value(Firestore.instance
    .collection("lockers")
    .where("userid", isEqualTo: "$_uid")
    .where("numero_serie", isEqualTo: "$_numeroSerie")
    .orderBy("userid").limit(1)
    .getDocuments());
```

---

Relacionados:

[Consulta composta firestore](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/366683/cloud-firestore-consulta-composta)

[Issue 1](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/815#issuecomment-465741365)

[Tipos de índices no Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview#composite_indexes)